# jQuery Cycle - two animations in one cycle

Tags: jquery, animation, cycle, effect, jquery-effects

I made slideshow with jQuery Cycle, but i have a problem with the timers. After couple cycles they're messing up. How can i merge two cycle animations in one function and with one timer?

Thank You for any help.

**xHTML:**

```
<div id="slideshow">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="image"><img src="test.jpg" /></div>
      <div class="description">Some text goes here</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="image"><img src="test.jpg" /></div>
      <div class="description">Some text goes here</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="image"><img src="test.jpg" /></div>
      <div class="description">Some text goes here</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var img = $(this).find('#slideshow div.image');
var desc = $(this).find('#slideshow div.description');
$('#slideshow ul').cycle({
    fx:    'scrollHorz', 
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout: 5000,
    next:   '.next',
    pause: 1,
    slideExpr: img
});
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx:    'scrollVert', 
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout: 5000,
    next:   '.next',
    pause: 1,
    slideExpr: desc
});
```

Comment: did you find and solution(s)...? looking for same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should:

1. Make your own custom function for the time handling issue (a rather simple JS function will do the trick).
2. Set the “timeout” property in your cycles to 0 so it won't auto-avance.
3. Use the available commands “prev” and “next” in your custom function in this form:

---

```
$('#slideshow').cycle('next');
```

I see the approach in your code, gotta thank you the great idea you just gave me tho.

Comment: can you please explain it a bit...
the slideshow as the ulo said is working fine but how can i use the pager??